# Stream a file on GCS to client via a proxy Cloud Function

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to have a cloud function that streams data byte by byte from a file on GCS.

For instance: I have a file on this path: `gs://my-bucket/folder/document.pdf` whose access is restricted to a single service account. 
Then I have a proxy Cloud Function, triggered by calling this URL: `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/gcs-proxy/folder/document.pdf`.
The name of the function is of course `gcs-proxy`.

Is there a way to "transfer" the file on GCS to the client without entirely read it to the function's memory and then send it to the client?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  The APIs for each platform support some sort of streaming interface.

Comment: Great. Can you send some info how to implement this? Golang is preferred but Javascript will also do. 
Thanks

Comment: There are examples on the Cloud Storage API documentation.  You will have to learn how to use node's stream api.